# Can anyone out there help me for Ocr business card scanner concept using tesseract-ocr in android?

Tags: android, tesseract

I am new in android .I want to make application of business card scanner using tesseract-ocr in android. I search lots of things related to these project.based on that I used these modules :

```
 1) eclipse sdk 
 2) eclipse ndk
 3) cygwin
 4) android-emulator
 5) windows-xp (os)
```

now the main problem is : I dont know how to run tesseract-ocr code with the help of ndk and cygwin. I have download the below given files. Can someone please let me know whether these files would be helpful to me or not.

```
 1) tesseract-3.00.tar.gz  (Link :- http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-3.00.tar.gz)
 2) tesseract-android-tools-1.00.tar.gz  (Link :- http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-android-tools-1.00.tar.gz)
```

many thanks, any knowledge about any particular solutions much appriciated !:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just download tesseract 2.03 and below is android.mk file compile it using android ndk it works fine for me.

```
ifneq ($(TARGET_SIMULATOR),true)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

BUILD_FOR_HOST:=0

#
# libocr (common)
#

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_:=      \
    ccutil/ambigs.cpp   \
    ccutil/basedir.cpp  \
    ccutil/bits16.cpp   \
    ccutil/boxread.cpp  \
    ccutil/clst.cpp     \
    ccutil/debugwin.cpp \
    ccutil/elst.cpp     \
    ccutil/elst2.cpp    \
    ccutil/errcode.cpp  \
    ccutil/globaloc.cpp \
    ccutil/hashfn.cpp   \
    ccutil/mainblk.cpp  \
    ccutil/memblk.cpp   \
    ccutil/memry.cpp    \
    ccutil/mfcpch.cpp   \
    ccutil/ocrshell.cpp \
    ccutil/scanutils.cpp    \
    ccutil/serialis.cpp \
    ccutil/strngs.cpp   \
    ccutil/tessdatamanager.cpp  \
    ccutil/tessopt.cpp  \
    ccutil/tordvars.cpp \
    ccutil/tprintf.cpp  \
    ccutil/unichar.cpp  \
    ccutil/unicharmap.cpp   \
    ccutil/unicharset.cpp   \
    ccutil/varable.cpp  \
    ccutil/ccutil.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    api/baseapi.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    viewer/scrollview.cpp   \
    viewer/svmnode.cpp  \
    viewer/svutil.cpp
#   viewer/svpaint.cpp  \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    cutil/bitvec.cpp    \
    cutil/cutil.cpp     \
    cutil/danerror.cpp  \
    cutil/efio.cpp      \
    cutil/emalloc.cpp   \
    cutil/freelist.cpp  \
    cutil/globals.cpp   \
    cutil/listio.cpp    \
    cutil/oldheap.cpp   \
    cutil/oldlist.cpp   \
    cutil/structures.cpp    \
    cutil/tessarray.cpp \
    cutil/cutil_class.cpp 

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    image/image.cpp     \
    image/imgbmp.cpp    \
    image/imgio.cpp     \
    image/imgs.cpp      \
    image/imgtiff.cpp   \
    image/bitstrm.cpp   \
    image/svshowim.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    liblept/adaptmap.c  \
    liblept/affine.c    \
    liblept/affinecompose.c \
    liblept/arithlow.c  \
    liblept/arrayaccess.c   \
    liblept/bardecode.c \
    liblept/baseline.c  \
    liblept/bbuffer.c   \
    liblept/bilinear.c  \
    liblept/binarize.c  \
    liblept/binexpand.c \
    liblept/binexpandlow.c  \
    liblept/binreduce.c \
    liblept/binreducelow.c  \
    liblept/blend.c     \
    liblept/bmf.c       \
    liblept/bmpio.c     \
    liblept/bmpiostub.c \
    liblept/boxbasic.c  \
    liblept/boxfunc1.c  \
    liblept/boxfunc2.c  \
    liblept/boxfunc3.c  \
    liblept/ccbord.c    \
    liblept/ccthin.c    \
    liblept/classapp.c  \
    liblept/colorcontent.c  \
    liblept/colormap.c  \
    liblept/colormorph.c    \
    liblept/colorquant1.c   \
    liblept/colorquant2.c   \
    liblept/colorseg.c  \
    liblept/compare.c   \
    liblept/conncomp.c  \
    liblept/convolve.c  \
    liblept/convolvelow.c   \
    liblept/correlscore.c   \
    liblept/dwacomb.2.c \
    liblept/dwacomblow.2.c  \
    liblept/edge.c      \
    liblept/endiantest.c    \
    liblept/enhance.c   \
    liblept/fhmtauto.c  \
    liblept/fhmtgen.1.c \
    liblept/fhmtgenlow.1.c  \
    liblept/flipdetect.c    \
    liblept/fliphmtgen.c    \
    liblept/fmorphauto.c    \
    liblept/fmorphgen.1.c   \
    liblept/fmorphgenlow.1.c    \
    liblept/fpix1.c     \
    liblept/fpix2.c     \
    liblept/gifio.c     \
    liblept/gifiostub.c \
    liblept/gplot.c     \
    liblept/graphics.c  \
    liblept/graymorph.c \
    liblept/graymorphlow.c  \
    liblept/grayquant.c \
    liblept/grayquantlow.c  \
    liblept/heap.c      \
    liblept/jbclass.c   \
    liblept/jpegio.c    \
    liblept/jpegiostub.c    \
    liblept/kernel.c    \
    liblept/list.c      \
    liblept/maze.c      \
    liblept/morphapp.c  \
    liblept/morph.c     \
    liblept/morphdwa.c  \
    liblept/morphseq.c  \
    liblept/numabasic.c \
    liblept/numafunc1.c \
    liblept/numafunc2.c \
    liblept/pageseg.c   \
    liblept/paintcmap.c \
    liblept/parseprotos.c   \
    liblept/partition.c \
    liblept/pix1.c      \
    liblept/pix2.c      \
    liblept/pix3.c      \
    liblept/pix4.c      \
    liblept/pixabasic.c \
    liblept/pixacc.c    \
    liblept/pixafunc1.c \
    liblept/pixafunc2.c \
    liblept/pixalloc.c  \
    liblept/pixarith.c  \
    liblept/pixconv.c   \
    liblept/pixtiling.c \
    liblept/pngio.c     \
    liblept/pngiostub.c \
    liblept/pnmio.c     \
    liblept/pnmiostub.c \
    liblept/projective.c    \
    liblept/psio.c      \
    liblept/psiostub.c  \
    liblept/ptra.c      \
    liblept/pts.c       \
    liblept/queue.c     \
    liblept/rank.c      \
    liblept/readbarcode.c   \
    liblept/readfile.c  \
    liblept/rop.c       \
    liblept/ropiplow.c  \
    liblept/roplow.c    \
    liblept/rotateam.c  \
    liblept/rotateamlow.c   \
    liblept/rotate.c    \
    liblept/rotateorth.c    \
    liblept/rotateorthlow.c \
    liblept/rotateshear.c   \
    liblept/runlength.c \
    liblept/sarray.c    \
    liblept/scale.c     \
    liblept/scalelow.c  \
    liblept/seedfill.c  \
    liblept/seedfilllow.c   \
    liblept/sel1.c      \
    liblept/sel2.c      \
    liblept/selgen.c    \
    liblept/shear.c     \
    liblept/skew.c      \
    liblept/stack.c     \
    liblept/textops.c   \
    liblept/tiffio.c    \
    liblept/tiffiostub.c    \
    liblept/utils.c     \
    liblept/viewfiles.c \
    liblept/warper.c    \
    liblept/watershed.c \
    liblept/writefile.c \
    liblept/zlibmem.c   \
    liblept/zlibmemstub.c   \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    ccstruct/blobbox.cpp    \
    ccstruct/blobs.cpp  \
    ccstruct/blread.cpp \
    ccstruct/callcpp.cpp    \
    ccstruct/coutln.cpp \
    ccstruct/detlinefit.cpp \
    ccstruct/genblob.cpp    \
    ccstruct/labls.cpp  \
    ccstruct/linlsq.cpp \
    ccstruct/lmedsq.cpp \
    ccstruct/mod128.cpp \
    ccstruct/normalis.cpp   \
    ccstruct/ocrblock.cpp   \
    ccstruct/ocrrow.cpp \
    ccstruct/otsuthr.cpp    \
    ccstruct/pageres.cpp    \
    ccstruct/pdblock.cpp    \
    ccstruct/points.cpp \
    ccstruct/polyaprx.cpp   \
    ccstruct/polyblk.cpp    \
    ccstruct/polyblob.cpp   \
    ccstruct/polyvert.cpp   \
    ccstruct/poutline.cpp   \
    ccstruct/quadlsq.cpp    \
    ccstruct/quadratc.cpp   \
    ccstruct/quspline.cpp   \
    ccstruct/ratngs.cpp \
    ccstruct/rect.cpp   \
    ccstruct/rejctmap.cpp   \
    ccstruct/statistc.cpp   \
    ccstruct/stepblob.cpp   \
    ccstruct/vecfuncs.cpp   \
    ccstruct/werd.cpp   \
    ccstruct/ccstruct.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    dict/choices.cpp    \
    dict/context.cpp    \
    dict/conversion.cpp \
    dict/dawg.cpp       \
    dict/dict.cpp       \
    dict/hyphen.cpp     \
    dict/permdawg.cpp   \
    dict/permngram.cpp  \
    dict/permute.cpp    \
    dict/states.cpp     \
    dict/stopper.cpp    \
    dict/trie.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    classify/adaptive.cpp   \
    classify/adaptmatch.cpp \
    classify/baseline.cpp   \
    classify/blobclass.cpp  \
    classify/chartoname.cpp \
    classify/classify.cpp   \
    classify/cluster.cpp    \
    classify/clusttool.cpp  \
    classify/cutoffs.cpp    \
    classify/extract.cpp    \
    classify/featdefs.cpp   \
    classify/flexfx.cpp \
    classify/float2int.cpp  \
    classify/fpoint.cpp \
    classify/fxdefs.cpp \
    classify/hideedge.cpp   \
    classify/intfx.cpp  \
    classify/intmatcher.cpp \
    classify/intproto.cpp   \
    classify/kdtree.cpp \
    classify/mf.cpp     \
    classify/mfdefs.cpp \
    classify/mfoutline.cpp  \
    classify/mfx.cpp    \
    classify/normfeat.cpp   \
    classify/normmatch.cpp  \
    classify/ocrfeatures.cpp\
    classify/outfeat.cpp    \
    classify/picofeat.cpp   \
    classify/protos.cpp \
    classify/speckle.cpp    \
    classify/xform2d.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    wordrec/associate.cpp   \
    wordrec/badwords.cpp    \
    wordrec/bestfirst.cpp   \
    wordrec/chop.cpp    \
    wordrec/chopper.cpp \
    wordrec/closed.cpp  \
    wordrec/drawfx.cpp  \
    wordrec/findseam.cpp    \
    wordrec/gradechop.cpp   \
    wordrec/heuristic.cpp   \
    wordrec/makechop.cpp    \
    wordrec/matchtab.cpp    \
    wordrec/matrix.cpp  \
    wordrec/metrics.cpp \
    wordrec/mfvars.cpp  \
    wordrec/olutil.cpp  \
    wordrec/outlines.cpp    \
    wordrec/pieces.cpp  \
    wordrec/plotedges.cpp   \
    wordrec/plotseg.cpp \
    wordrec/render.cpp  \
    wordrec/seam.cpp    \
    wordrec/split.cpp   \
    wordrec/tally.cpp   \
    wordrec/tessinit.cpp    \
    wordrec/tface.cpp   \
    wordrec/wordclass.cpp   \
    wordrec/wordrec.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    ccmain/tessvars.cpp \
    ccmain/tstruct.cpp  \
    ccmain/reject.cpp   \
    ccmain/callnet.cpp  \
    ccmain/charcut.cpp  \
    ccmain/docqual.cpp  \
    ccmain/paircmp.cpp  \
    ccmain/adaptions.cpp    \
    ccmain/ambigsrecog.cpp  \
    ccmain/applybox.cpp \
    ccmain/blobcmp.cpp  \
    ccmain/charsample.cpp   \
    ccmain/control.cpp  \
    ccmain/expandblob.cpp   \
    ccmain/fixspace.cpp \
    ccmain/fixxht.cpp   \
    ccmain/imgscale.cpp \
    ccmain/matmatch.cpp \
    ccmain/osdetect.cpp \
    ccmain/output.cpp   \
    ccmain/pagewalk.cpp \
    ccmain/pgedit.cpp   \
    ccmain/scaleimg.cpp \
    ccmain/tessbox.cpp  \
    ccmain/tesseractclass.cpp   \
    ccmain/tfacepp.cpp  \
    ccmain/thresholder.cpp  \
    ccmain/varabled.cpp \
    ccmain/werdit.cpp   \
    ccmain/tessedit.cpp
#   ccmain/tessembedded.cpp \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES_+=      \
    textord/alignedblob.cpp \
    textord/bbgrid.cpp  \
    textord/blkocc.cpp  \
    textord/colfind.cpp \
    textord/colpartition.cpp    \
    textord/colpartitionset.cpp \
    textord/drawedg.cpp \
    textord/drawtord.cpp    \
        textord/edgblob.cpp \
    textord/edgloop.cpp \
    textord/fpchop.cpp  \
    textord/gap_map.cpp \
    textord/imagefind.cpp   \
    textord/linefind.cpp    \
    textord/makerow.cpp \
    textord/oldbasel.cpp    \
    textord/pagesegmain.cpp \
    textord/pithsync.cpp    \
    textord/pitsync1.cpp    \
    textord/scanedg.cpp \
    textord/sortflts.cpp    \
    textord/strokewidth.cpp \
    textord/tabfind.cpp \
    textord/tablefind.cpp   \
    textord/tabvector.cpp   \
    textord/topitch.cpp \
    textord/tordmain.cpp    \
    textord/tospace.cpp \
    textord/tovars.cpp  \
    textord/underlin.cpp    \
    textord/wordseg.cpp     \
    textord/workingpartset.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES_+=     \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccmain        \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/api   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccstruct      \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/cstruct       \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/cutil     \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccutil        \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccmain        \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/image         \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/liblept   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/dict      \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/classify      \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/viewer    \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/wordrec       \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/textord   \
    external/jpeg

LOCAL_CFLAGS_:=         \
    -DGRAPHICS_DISABLED \
    -DHAVE_LIBLEPT          \
        -O3
#   -DFST_DISABLED      \
#   -DDISABLE_INTEGER_MATCHING  \
#   -DDISABLE_DOC_DICT  \

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES:=    \
    libjpeg

#
# libocr (native)
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES_)    \
    api/jni.cpp         \
    liblept/_open_memstream.c   \
    liblept/_fopencookie.c      \
    liblept/_fmemopen.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=$(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES_)
LOCAL_CFLAGS:=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS_)
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES:=$(LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES_)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= \
    liblog

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MODULE:= libocr

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE:= false

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifeq ($(BUILD_FOR_HOST),1)

#
# libocr (host)
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES_) api/jni.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=$(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES_)
LOCAL_CFLAGS:=$(LOCAL_CFLAGS_)
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES:=$(LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES_)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:=$(LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES_)

LOCAL_MODULE:= libocr

include $(BUILD_HOST_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#
# tesseract test (host)
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:= tesseract

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    api/tesseractmain.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS:= \
    -DGRAPHICS_DISABLED \
    -DHAVE_LIBLEPT      \
    -DFST_DISABLED      \
    -DBUILD_HOST

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccutil        \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccstruct  \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/image     \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/dict      \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/classify  \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/wordrec   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/viewer    \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/cutil     \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/textord   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/api   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccmain

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= \
    libocr

include $(BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE)

#
# simple raw-YUV test (host)
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:= tesstest 

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
    ccmain/test.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS:= \
    -DGRAPHICS_DISABLED \
    -DHAVE_LIBLEPT      \
    -DFST_DISABLED      \
    -DBUILD_HOST

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccutil        \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccstruct  \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/image     \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/liblept   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/dict      \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/classify  \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/wordrec   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/viewer    \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/cutil     \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/textord   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/api   \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/ccmain

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= \
    libocr

include $(BUILD_HOST_EXECUTABLE)

endif #BUILD_FOR_HOST

endif #TARGET_SIMULATOR
```

Comment: Hi Girish,Thanku very much for your reply  , but i am confused . I download the tesseract 2.03 . I dnt know the procedure to run this code . I want to run it with eclipse . but the code is not match with it . please help me with proper guidence.

Comment: just download tesseract from git repositary and than try to compile using android ndk. tesseract is given at this [link](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/tesseract.git;a=summary).

Comment: Thanx for response Girish , Your link is not working . I download tesseract 2.03 from this link (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-2.03.tar.gz&can=4&q=). Can this code is perfect for me . please reply . I need ur help. thanx again.

Comment: Thanx for your response, My email-id is  : "hardik@magicboxindia.com". please send me the folder . so I can try it with ndk. thanks girish.